# Advice need to fix flex/bootstrap prob

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I thought I was getting to understand Bootstrap and Flex when it suddenly started doing strange things and I cannot figure out where I have gone wrong. The issues I am experiencing are:

1. The container is not moving to the length of its  content. It refuses to budge beyond a height of 210px. I don't have that length written anywhere.
2. On resizing the screen, the three columns in the top row do not resize in such a way to maintain the full 100% width. They just make a beeline to the left and squish up there as though they are cowering in fear!
3. In the second row, I have two columns. The right hand column contain images which stubbornly refuses to resize though I am using the img-responsive class ... BUT the left hand column does resize but really squishes up to an intolerable tiny unreadable width

Below are my HTML and CSS codes.

Really appreciate any help.

Thanks
Terry

```css
body {
  background-color: #B09D32;
}

.container {
 max-width: 970px;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 padding: 0px;
}

.header {
 padding: 0px;
  display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
}

.headcol1 {
 background-color: #ffff00;
 color: red;
 height: 100px;
}

.headcol2 {
 background-color: #ff0000;
 color: white;
 height: 100px;
}

.headcol3 {
 background-color: #ff00ff;
 height: 100px;
}

.content {
 padding: 5px;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
}

.contentcol1 {
 background-color: #CCCCFF;
 color: green;
 height: 100px;
}

.contentcol2 {
 background-color: #FFFFCC;
 color: blue;
 height: 100px;
}

.contentcol2_row0 {
 outline: 1px solid red !important;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.contentcol2_row1 {
 outline: 1px solid red !important;
  display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.contentcol2_row2 {
 outline: 1px solid red !important;
  display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
}
.contentcol2_row1_col1, .contentcol2_row2_col2 {
 outline: 1px dotted blue;
}

.contentcol2_row1_col2, .contentcol2_row2_col1 {
 outline: 1px solid green;
}

/* ------- VERTICAL MENU -------- */

ul#vertmenu {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: outside none none;
}

ul#vertmenu li {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #E5EAED;
 background: transparent linear-gradient(#FFF, #F8F8F8) repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}

ul#vertmenu li.selected {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #35B5F4;
}

ul#vertmenu li a {
    background: transparent none repeat scroll 0px center;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    color: #666;
    font-weight: bold;
}

ul#vertmenu li a {
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul#vertmenu li a:hover {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #CC3300;
 background: transparent linear-gradient(#FFF, #E69980) repeat scroll 0% 0%;
 color: #7A1F00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Grid layout test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gridtest.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="header">
  <div class="col-md-4 headcol1">Column 1 - Logo</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 headcol2">Column 2 - Title</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 headcol3">Column 3 - A form</div>
 </div><!-- closes header div -->

 <div class="content">
  <div class="col-md-4 contentcol1">Content column 1 - Vertical nav</div>
  <div class="col-md-8 contentcol2">Content column 2 containing nested rows. Each row contains two columns.
   <div class="contentcol2_row0">
    <div class="col-md-12"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/610x250" class="img-responsive"></div>
   </div><!-- closes contentcol2_row0 div -->
   <div class="contentcol2_row1">
    <div class="contentcol2_row1_col1 col-md-8">This is Content column 2, row 1, column 1</div>
    <div class="contentcol2_row1_col2 col-md-4"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/170x170" class="img-responsive"></div>
   </div><!-- closes contentcol2_row1 div -->
   <div class="contentcol2_row2">
    <div class="contentcol2_row2_col1 col-md-4"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/170x170" class="img-responsive"></div>
    <div class="contentcol2_row2_col2 col-md-8">This is Content column 2, row 2, column 2</div>
   </div><!-- closes contentcol2_row2 div -->

  </div><!-- closes contentcol2 div -->
 </div><!-- closes content div -->
</div><!-- closes container div -->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in `<body>` tag. Basically replaced the `content`, `header` and `contentcol2_row` classes to just `row`.

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 headcol1">Column 1 - Logo</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 headcol2">Column 2 - Title</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 headcol3">Column 3 - A form</div>
    </div><!-- closes header div -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 contentcol1">Content column 1 - Vertical nav</div>
        <div class="col-md-8 contentcol2">Content column 2 containing nested rows. Each row contains two columns.
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/610x250" class="img-responsive"></div>
            </div><!-- closes contentcol2_row0 div -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="contentcol2_row1_col1 col-md-8">This is Content column 2, row 1, column 1</div>
                <div class="contentcol2_row1_col2 col-md-4"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/170x170" class="img-responsive"></div>
            </div><!-- closes contentcol2_row1 div -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="contentcol2_row2_col1 col-md-4"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/170x170" class="img-responsive"></div>
                <div class="contentcol2_row2_col2 col-md-8">This is Content column 2, row 2, column 2</div>
            </div><!-- closes contentcol2_row2 div -->

        </div><!-- closes contentcol2 div -->
    </div><!-- closes content div -->
</div><!-- closes container div -->

</body>
```

Comment: Hi Abbas. Why does the container not "contain" all the rows? The background colour of container is white and this stops after the second row. It does not 'contain' the nested rows. Why is that?